# "selfdestruct" deprecated in Solidity 0.8.18

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, randomness, selfdestruct

I have noticed that although the new compiler 0.8.18 has nice new feature in form of a **block.prevrandao** , it also has a deprecated **selfdestruct** feature. Is there an alternative to that or is it gone forever?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENCED

pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract RandomNumber{

    address owner;

    constructor(){
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function getRandomNumber() external view returns(uint) {
        return block.prevrandao % 139;
    }
    function deleteContract() external {
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Not an owner;");
        selfdestruct(payable(msg.sender));
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're perfectly allowed to keep using it, the depreciation has been put in place because the SELFDESTRUCT opcode most likely going to be deleted in an upcoming fork (https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4758), which would break contracts/protocols relying on it when that happens. Knowing that however, you can still keep using it, as long as you understand the risk it causes (which might just be perfectly fine in some usecases, since most contracts that use it are short lived anyways)

Comment: Also, note that prevrandao isnt a "solidity feature" but merely a syntax change to reflect a change in the ETH network, it gets compiled to the exact same thing than the old `block.difficulty` was compiled to, and  it will return the difficulty if it's used in an EVM-compatible chain that doesn't implement EIP-4399 (just as `block.difficulty` (from 0.8.17 and prior versions) returns the previous block's randao output on ethereum mainnet)

Comment: many people opposed to this EIP , including developers of Optimism. I am also against it. I don't think it will go live, it is inactive for 2 years now

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest code from OpenZeppelin repo/contracts/utils/Address.sol

```
        (bool success,) = payable(owner).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        if (!success) {
            revert("call{value} failed");
        }
```